# How C# Dll accepts a logger interface and write to that log file

Tags: c#, logging, dll, error-logging

I have a C# Class library and I have to add logging. This class library is supposed to be used by multiple applications which having different logging  mechanisms (like the NLog, Log4Net etc.). So I have to write Dll logs to the application's log file which they are using.
For that how can I implement a C# dll which is accepting a logger interface and to write to that log file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a generic logging package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` that contains a set of simple `ILogger` interfaces. Most larger logging frameworks include out-of-the-box adapters for these interfaces. So it should be easy within the applications to wrap the logging to whichever logger that product uses.

You can find a simple example that should do most of what you need in [this change](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/commit/886e8a5336f91f74dc197ce9360ce706a6f436b2)